# Prepare for Segue to UITabBarController Tab

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue

I want to pass information from a `ViewController` to a `UITabBarController` so that I can access certain information from the view controller in the 3rd tab of the `UITabBarController`.

However, the issue is my program keeps crashing when I try to do so. Here is my code so far:

I call the segue like so:

```
self.firstName = user.first_name
self.lastName = user.last_name
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("OffersView", sender: self)
```

And I override the `prepareForSegue` function so that I can pass information in this function like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "OffersView"){
        let barViewControllers = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
        let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers![2] as ProfileController
        destinationViewController.firstName = self.firstName
        destinationViewController.lastName = self.lastName
    }
}
```

When I try to set the `destinationViewController` (on the second line in the code above), my code crashes. I'm not sure why as I've looked on numerous StackOverflow posts such as

[Swift tab bar view prepareforsegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307903/swift-tab-bar-view-prepareforsegue) and [Pass data from tableview to tab bar view controller in Swift.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296742/pass-data-from-tableview-to-tab-bar-view-controller-in-swift) but have not have much success. Do I possibly need to create a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` class and pass information through that? Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It crashes with what error message?

Comment: @rdelmar it doesn't seem to display any particular error message.

Comment: In a test app, your code worked fine for me after changing the two "as" words to "as!" in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you did that? I added in an exclamation point in front of the "as" word but I got an error saying "Expected type after as"
 @rdelmar

Comment: It goes after the as, **as!**, not before.

Comment: @rdelmar ah yes sorry I wasn't clear. I did put it after the as but I get the error as I have said above. This is how my code looks: 

`let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers![2] as! ProfileController`

and the error is "Expected type after as"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74980/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user1871869).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, as discovered after a discussion, was that the tab bar controller's children were embedded in navigation controllers, so the code needed to be changed to this,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    let barViewControllers = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController 
    let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController 
    let destinationViewController = nav.topviewcontroller as ProfileController 
    destinationViewController.firstName = self.firstName
    destinationViewController.lastName = self.lastName 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3, xcode 8 that code would be like

```
let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
let destinationViewController = nav.viewControllers[0] as! YourViewController
        destinationViewController.varTest = _varValue
```

Comment: How do you find out which tab is chosen and set the variable for that particular tabView?

Comment: In my case I needed to navigate to "YourViewController". My guess is in viewControllers array is stored all controllers (I'm new in swift).

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4** solution without force optional unwrapping

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let barVC = segue.destination as? UITabBarController {
        barVC.viewControllers?.forEach {
            if let vc = $0 as? YourViewController {
                vc.firstName = self.firstName
                vc.lastName = self.lastName
            }
        }
    }
}
```