# after call presentViewController tab bar is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

test1 is the first view in the tarbarcontorller..
after I call presentViewController tab bar is missing 
How can i solve it??

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
TestTableViewController *TestTableViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test1"];
TestTableViewController.memberid = memberid;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:TestTableViewController];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should present your TabBarController, and not the first view of your tab bar controller. It will display the first view in your tab bar controller properly.

Comment: I would like to pass a var to the first viewcontorller.  how can i do that??

Comment: if i change the storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test1"] to tarbarcontorller.  TestTableViewController.memberid = memberid; <- crash.  and also the navigation bar is mssing.

Comment: If you want to pass a variable to your next controller, use a segue. With TabBarController, it works [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29573224/4020535).