# Perform segue from tabbarcontroller in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a TabBarController with 4 tabs. When the second tab is selected I would like to make an api call to get data & then, once the data returns, display the data in the destination view controller (let's call it SecondViewController).

I believe what I should do is wire up the SecondViewController to the TabBarController with a 'show' segue in the storyboard. However, it seems that I  have to wire the TabBarController to the SecondViewController with a 'relationship segue' in-order to have the tab icon displaying. So I have both wired up.

When the second tab is selected the SecondViewController is immediately displayed before the necessary data is returned. Any thoughts on how to address this issue?

I have googled around for hours and have not found any helpful advice. A somewhat relevant stackoverflow question I have found is [Prepare for Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572744/prepare-for-segue-to-uitabbarcontroller-tab)

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry what you want is not possible in iOS.**

You can do one thing initially put relationship to a blank page. When you get the response from API you can reset the page. You can programatically replace your blank page with SecondViewController.

**OR**

You can do one thing initially put relationship to a SecondViewController page with no data. When you get the response from API you can reset the page.