# Segue from Table View controller to Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "naarPersoonView"
    {
        let tabCtrl = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let vc = tabCtrl.viewControllers![0] as! PersoonViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        vc.persoon = personen[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }
}
```

When i try to send a person from my TableViewController to my persoonViewController( Tab view Controller ) it gave me this error 
`Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10ff68758) to 'DriesVD.PersoonViewController' (0x10e312750).`

Comment: what type of personen array & persoon var ??

Comment: i made a class Persoon and in this controller I made a var persoon wich is from type Persoon and a personen array where i've put my objects of Persoon in

Comment: Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296742/pass-data-from-tableview-to-tab-bar-view-controller-in-swift

Comment: What type is `PersoonViewController`?  Is it a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: No from UITabBarController

Comment: How are you setting the `ViewControllers` of your `tabCtrl`?  When you are accessing your `tabCtrl.viewControllers![0]`, it is receiving a subclass of `UIViewController`.  This is not the same as a `UITabBarController` (which `PersoonViewController` is a subclass of), so it is throwing this error.

Comment: Yeah thank you I solved it

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "naarPersoonView"
    {
        let tabCtrl =  segue.destination as! UITabBarController
        let desView: PersoonViewController = tabCtrl.viewControllers?.first as! PersoonViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        desView.persoon = personen[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }
}
```

I solved my problem with the example above thanks for all your quick responses